# get all data in couchbase

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchbase

i want get all documents in a bucket, but the documents is so big, there is about 40 million documents. so i create a view, and get 1 million documents every time by set the limit argument, but it always cause timeout error halfway through, how can i get the documents,

thank you